# How to disable the indentation dotted line in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, text-editor

[image]

see these dotted lines there on every indent...
How do I turn it off?

I must have accidentally hit some keyboard shortcut but I can't find this anywhere in the settings.

Sorry, this is a really dumb question, but these lines really bother me and I didn't know where else to turn :)

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Toggle it on/off with: Edit > Advanced > View white space

The default hotkey is usually <kbd>ctrl+E,S</kbd> (I think this is for General or C# developer settings)

If you use Resharper, you may find you need to use <kbd>ctrl+R,ctrl+W</kbd> (this may also apply for C++ developer settings)

*(**Note** that the hotkey may be **different** for different key binding schemes, and can be customised in Tools > Options > Keyboard. Also, Addins and Extensions (e.g. Resharper) may modify them or add their own equivalents. But the bound key will be displayed on the above menu so it's easy to determine what the hotkey is on your PC)*

Comment: If you have resharper installed then  `ctrl+R,ctrl+W`  is shortcut.

Comment: @mehul9595: That is only the case when allowing re-sharper to override C# hotkey settings during re-sharper setup.

Comment: On (my) Visual Studio 2012 (without resharper) `ctrl+R,ctrl+W` does the trick.

Comment: For Visual Studio 2015, you need to use `ctrl+R, ctrl+W` same as in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: @ShivamChopra: Please read my answer. The keypress you quote may be provided by Resharper rather than being the default from Visual Studio. The bindings for this in VS2015 are the same as in VS2013, VS2012, VS2010, but the exact keypresses _may be different for you depending on the binding scheme you chose on installation, or the extensions that you have installed._

Answer (score 14):

This is a very useful feature as it allows you to quickly check longer code sections to see which logic branch that code belongs to.

To toggle this:

Edit->Advanced->View White Space or use short cut (<kbd>CTRL+E</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>)