# Dotted lines there on every indent in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio

I am seeing dotted lines in my C# code in VS 2010. Dotted lines appear in every indent. This really bothers me. I must have typed some shortcut key but I'm not able to revert it back.

How can I disable it? What is the use of the dotted lines anyway?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable the indentation dotted line in VS 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384431/how-to-disable-the-indentation-dotted-line-in-vs-2010)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

the 'dotted lines' are part of the editors way of showing you where the indentation levels begin. this is a very useful feature as it allows you to quickly scan longer code sections to see which logic branch that code belongs to.

to change this:

Edit->Advanced->View White Space (CTRL+E,S)

Comment: no worries, always nice when its a simple (if hidden) fix!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like "view whitespace" is turned on.  Under VS2010 you find it under:

Edit->Advanced->View

Answer (score 1):

You can disable and enable it from the main menu using Edit->Advanced->View White Space. It just shows all the white spaces in the solution. It means that all the tabs also will be drawn by the arrows