# Visual studio IDE styling issue

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Accidentally I have pressed some key and the following dot dot line appear in my visual studio-2013 IDE.

Could anyone can tell me how to remote this, any shortcut or options?[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable the indentation dotted line in VS 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384431/how-to-disable-the-indentation-dotted-line-in-vs-2010)

Comment: Thanks got it perfectly (Y)